# Inherit ES6/TS class from non-class

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Given the class is extended from non-class (including, but not limited to, function),

```
function Fn() {} 

class Class extends Fn {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

what are the the consequences? What do the specs say on that?

It looks like the current implementations of Babel, Google V8 and Mozilla Spidermonkey are ok with that, and TypeScript throws

> Type '() => void' is not a constructor function type

If this is a valid ES2015 code, what's the proper way to handle it in TypeScript?

Comment: The result of `class Foo { ... }` in ES2015 is a (constructor) function named `Foo`. So, naturally, you can use `extends` with either a function or the result of a `class`, because they're both actually functions. (i.e., `class` is only special syntax for defining functions; there is no such thing as a "class object"). I don't know what's going on with TypeScript, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### TypeScript Part

Up to now, the [spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#a6-classes) says a `extends` claus must be followed by a *TypeReference*. And a [TypeReference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#a1-types) must be in the form of  `A.B.C<TypeArgument>`, like `MyModule.MyContainer<MyItem>`. So, syntactically your code is right. But it is not the typing case.

The spec says the `BaseClass` must be a valid typescript class. However, the spec is outdated, as said [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#811-class-heritage-specification).  Now TypeScript allows expressions in extends clause, as long as expressions are computed to a constructor function. The definition is, well, implementation based. You can see it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/checker.ts#L2943). Simply put, a expression can be counted as constructor if it implements `new() {}` interface.

### ES2015 Part

So, your problem is plain function is not recognized as constructor in TypeScript, which is arguable because ES2015 spec only requires the object has a `[[construct]]` internal method. While user-defined function object does have it.

[ES2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation) requires `BaseClass` [is a constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-isconstructor) at **runtime**. An object `isConstructor` if it has `[[construct]]` [internal methd](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget). The spec says `[[construct]]` is an internal method for [Function Object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-objects). User functions are instances of `Function Objects`, so naturally they are constructor. But [builtin function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-built-in-function-objects) and [arrow function](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/arrow-functions/) can have no `[[construct]]`.

For example, the following code will throw runtime `TypeError` because `parseInt` is a builtin function and does not have `[[construct]]`

```
new parseInt()
// TypeError: parseInt is not a constructor
```

And from ECMAScript

> Arrow functions are like built-in functions in that both lack .prototype and any [[Construct]] internal method. So new (() => {}) throws a TypeError but otherwise arrows are like functions:

**As a rule of thumb, any function without `prototype` is not `new`-able.**

### Work Around

In short, not every function is constructor, TypeScript captures this by requiring `new() {}`. However, user-defined function is constructor.

To work around this, the easiest way is declare `Fn` as a variable, and cast it into constructor.

```
interface FnType {}
var Fn: {new(): FnType} = (function() {}) as any

class B extends Fn {}
```

### Reasoning the incompatiblity

**DISCALIMER: I'm not a TypeScript core contributor, but just a TS fan who has several side project related to TS. So this section is my personal guess.**

TypeScript is a project originated in [2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript#cite_note-1), when ES2015 was still looming in dim dark. TypeScript didn't have a good reference for class semantics.

Back then, the [main goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) of TypeScript was to keep compatible with ES3/5. So, `new`ing a function is legal in TypeScript, because it is also legal in ES3/5. At the same time, TypeScript also aims to capture programming errors. `extends` a function might be an error because the function might not be a sensible constructor (say, a function solely for side effect). `extends` did not even exist in ES3/5! So TypeScript could freely define its own usage of `extends`, making `extends` must pair with `class` variable. This made *TypeScript* more *TypeSafe*, while being compatible with JavaScript.

Now, ES2015 spec is finalized. JavaScript also has a `extends` keyword! Then incompatibility comes. There are [efforts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4789) to resolve incompatibility. However, still problems exist. `() => void` or `Function` type should not be *extends*able, as stated above due to builtin function. The following code will break

```
var a: (x: string) => void = eval
new a('booom')
```

On the other hand, if a `ConstructorInterface` was introduced into TypeScript and every function literal implemented it, then backward incompatibility would emerge. The following code compiles now but not when `ConstructorInterface` was introduced

```
var a = function (s) {}
a = parseInt // compile error because parseInt is not assignable to constructor
```

Of course, TS team can have a solution that balancing these two options. But this is not a high priority. Also, if *salsa*, the codename for TS powered JavaScript, is fully implemented. This problem will be solved naturally.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed summary. So, it is fine for ES2015 and shouldn't accidentally break with later ES implementations, isn't it? Are there any problems with `var Fn = <FunctionConstructor> function() {}` as more concise way to do the same thing in TS?

Comment: Yes, a plain function literal is a legal constructor. And, you cannot cast function literal into constructor in TS because incompatible types are not convertible, in this case they are `() => void` and `new ()`. Casting to `any` is a workaround TS provides intentionally.

Comment: I see. I wonder why TS doesn't throw anything [with that](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20Fn%20%3D%20%3CFunctionConstructor%3E%20function%28%29%20{}%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Class%20extends%20Fn%20{%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28%29%20{%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super%28%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20}%0D%0A}%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Class%28%29%3B) then.

Comment: Because TS allows **bivariant** type assertion: a subtype can be casted to a supertype, and a supertype can be casted to subtype. `FunctionConstructor` is declared as `{new (...args): Function} & {(...args): Function}`, so it is a subtype of `() => void`, thus castable. You can refer to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#416-type-assertions) for more formal explanation

Answer (score 4):

> what are the the consequences? What do the specs say on that?

It is the same as extending a "EcmaScript 5" class. Your declare a constructor function and no prototype at all. You can extend it without any problem.

But for TypeScript, there is a big difference between `function Fn() {}` and `class Fn {}`. The both are not of the same type.

The first one is a just a function returning nothing (and TypeScript show it with the `() => void`). The second one is a constructor function. TypeScript refuse to do an extends on a non constructor function.

If one day javascript refuse to do that, it will break many javascript codes. Because at the moment, `function Fn() {}` is the most used way to declare a class in pure javascript. But from the TypeScript point of view, this is not "type safe".

I think the only way for TypeScript is to use a class :

```
class Fn {} 

class Class extends Fn {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I answer your question but I was very interested how to extend a JS function by a TypeScript class so I tried following:

**fn.js** (note the `.js` extension!)

```
function Fn() {
    console.log("2");
}
```

**c.ts**

```
declare class Fn {}

class C extends Fn {
    constructor() {
        console.log("1");
        super();
        console.log("3");
    }
}

let c = new C();
c.sayHello();
```

Then I ran:

```
$ tsc --target es5 c.ts | cat fn.js c.js | node  # or es6
```

and the output is:

```
1
2
3
Hello!
```

Note, that this is not code for production use but rather a workaround for cases when you don't have time to convert some old JS file to TypeScript.

If I was in OP situation, I would try to convert `Fn` to a class because it makes code easier for others in a team.

Answer (score 1):

This is indirectly related to [TypeScript interface to describe class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351369/typescript-interface-to-describe-class)

Although the `typeof` a class is `function`, there is no Class (nor Interface) in Typescript which is the super class of all classes.

functions however are all interfaced by `Function`

I guess to be consistent with Javascript, `Function` should be probably be a class, all functions should be of that class and all classes should extend it...